# Textviews don't get animated in a SharedContentTransitionAnimation

Tags: android, android-transitions

I came across this solution: [How can I scale textviews using shared element transitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599824/how-can-i-scale-textviews-using-shared-element-transitions/26813670#26813670)

But this is not working, when I use this solution, I don't get any animations at all.
The problem is the size of the text inside textviews, and the color of the text. They don't get animated and the movement animation looks really weird. Should I make a animation that runs after the SharedContentTransitions have completed? Or is there a fix that makes this issue a whole lot easier to fix?