# Android - Different transitions with multiple shared elements

Tags: android, textview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm working with Android Lollipop Transitions, and I've sumbled upon the following problem:

1. I have `CardView` with an `ImageView` and, on top of it, a `TextView`.
2. When I click on the card, a new Activity is launched, and it contains both the `ImageView` and the `TextView` in different positions.
3. If I don't include the `TextView` in the `Transition` as a shared element, it suddenly dissapears [goes behind] the `ImageView`, which doesn't look, well, great.
4. If I include it, it doesn't scale the text nicely and suddenly changes to the final size (I am aware of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599824/how-can-i-scale-textviews-using-shared-element-transitions) already, but the problem is I want to keep also the default `ImageView` `Transition`, which is a combination of a `ChangeBounds` `Transition`, a `ChangeImageTransform`, ... among others).

So, anybody knows how to have different transitions being thrown for different shared views when launching the new `Activity`?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

This is achievable extending the Transition class. Since I wanted to animate differently an ImageView and a TextView, I just wrote a `TextTransform` child class of`Transform`, analogous to the `ChangeImageTransform` one which is part of the Android API 21+. The key was overriding this method (shown the case for ChangeImageTransform which looks for `ImageView` objects):

```
@Override
private void captureValues(TransitionValues transitionValues) {
    View view = transitionValues.view;
    if (!(view instanceof ImageView) || view.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        return;
    }
    (...)
}
```

Then you apply all transforms to the new scene, and relevant transform will be attached to their corresponding views:

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <fade android:fadingMode="fade_out" />
    <changeBounds />
    <changeImageTransform />
    <com.mypackage.transforms.TextTransform />
    <fade android:fadingMode="fade_in" />
</transitionSet>
```

And then you set this `Transition` on the OnCreate method of the new `Activity` using `setSharedElementEnterTransition(inflatedTransitionSet);`

Answer (score 2):

The way you pointed to it in your answer can be applied for this purpose but it's actually for accepting only suitable `View` types by a special `transition` (such as only `ImageView`s for `ChangeImageTransform`).

You can use **`addTarget(Class targetType)`** instead:

```
final Transition transition = new TransitionSet()
    .addTransition(new ChangeTransform()).addTarget(TextView.class) // Only for TextViews
    .addTransition(new ChangeImageTransform()).addTarget(ImageView.class) // Only for ImageViews
    .addTransition(new ChangeBounds()); // For both

setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
```

This way is more simple and more logical. Also, it can be used for some other filterings (by `transitionName` and etc). See `addTarget()` overloaded types.