# Detect textSize of TextViews both in start scene and end scene in custom transition

Tags: android, transition

I'm writing a custom `Transition` for textSize of `TextView` as the shared element enter transition between two activities. I'm stuck with implementing the `captureStartValues` and `captureEndValues`. `TransitionValues.view` in these two methods is the same instance, which is just the TextView at start scene(if I add this transition in starting activity) or at end scene(if I add it in launching activity).

The accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599824/how-can-i-scale-textviews-using-shared-element-transitions#) uses `SharedElementCallback`(in his github demo) to set TextView's textSize which results in the `TextSizeTransition` to detect the correct textSize in start scene and end scene.

What I want to know is that, is it possible to detect the textSize  of TextViews both in start scene and end scene just in custom `TextSizeTransition` without using `SharedElementCallback`?

Maybe like `ChangeBounds`, it captures start values and end values just using the target view from `TransitionValues` directly(it seems so from the source code).

Thanks.